# Perl Class 'LWP::Simple' Not Recognized in Eclipse on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, perl

I've installed cygwin and download `LWP::Simple`. I receive the below response inside of cygwin, so the module has been installed.  But inside of eclipse, I'm getting an error when I try to use the `use LWP::Simple;` statement.  It says the module can't be found.  How is this possible?

```
$ perl -MLWP -le "print(LWP->VERSION)"
6.13
```

Comment: When typing "echo $PERL5LIB" in cygwin nothing shows up,.  Where do i set the path to in Windows?  Should the path be set to the project directory I created in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

When you're in cygwin, do:

```
echo $PERL5LIB
```

See what paths are being used as search trees for imported modules.

Compare this to PERL5LIB in the environment in which Eclipse is running perl:

```
print $ENV{"PERL5LIB"} . "\n";
```

If the PERL5LIB is empty or missing directories, that's your partial answer The rest of the answer is how to get it back.

Also, please add details on how you're running perl in eclipse. It may provide a vital clue to someone who's had the same problem. I've heard of people needed to modify how perl is run in EPIC -- is that it? Is there a command line for perl set up in the settings?

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment

Comment: @Borodin As I mentioned, it's a partial answer at the very least. The rest of the answer depends on feedback from the OP, but I hear what you're saying. I don't think a downvote was necessary.

Comment: Your whole post is a question about contents of `PERL5LIB` and what to do if that is wrong. It may well not be an answer at all, depending on the OP's response to that question. You can't just throw out wild ideas without checking first that they are the right answer. It may be a way for you to get experience points but it doesn't help anyone

Comment: When typing "echo $PERL5LIB" in cygwin nothing shows up,. Where do i set the path to in Windows? Should the path be set to the project directory I created in eclipse?

Comment: When you click on the perl project properties, what setting is there for the perl executable command e.g. "perl -w" and what @INC or PERL5LIB settings are specified? Is there an option there to add paths to @INC? Find out where your LWP is installed and add that path. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by correcting my system environmental variables in Windows by going to sysdm.cpl | Advanced| Environmental Variables| in the System variables section | add ";c:\cywgin64\bin" in the path variable section.  Then restarting the computer.